# Objective C change the value of an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, ios4

```
ElementObject1 *o1=   // An XML document's element with some value

ElementObject2 *o2=   //A new element with a new value to be replaced
```

I want that "the value at the address which o1 points to" to be changed with the "value at the address which o2 points to"

when I say

```
o1=o2 this does not work
```

I just want to simply edit this XML object and change some of its elements with new elements.

How can I do this with the Objective-c way? copy copy zone ?

Comment: have you got it to work?

Comment: I followed another way, but thanks for your reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes , you have to implement the method

```
- (id)copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone
```

and then say

```
o1 = [o2 copy];
```

Don't forget to release o1

```
[o1 release];
```

and to add the protocol

<`NSCopying`> in your Model @interface

Comment: `copyWithZone:` is not a delegate method.   And the protocol is `NSCopying`, not `NSCoding`.

Comment: yes, sorry. I was a bit to fast and copied the wrong protocol from my models. Also I didn't know that is wasn't a delegate function. Corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to make two distinct objects that have the same value?  If so, try:

```
o1 = [o2 copy];
```

Be sure to do:

```
[o1 release];
```

When you're done.

If you're trying to have both pointers point to the same object, what you have above (o1 = o2) should work.  Make sure to retain o1 if you want to keep it.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is no general facility to "change the value of an object." You can freely change the value of a variable, but objects can only be altered through their interface of messages and properties. If an object does not provide a method to mutate in a certain way, then you can't alter it that way. Some classes have methods that completely replace their contents — NSMutableArray and NSMutableString are the two that come immediately to mind — but there's no general way to do that with an arbitrary object in Objective-C.